# How to deploy each app of a Django project into different servers

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, hosting

For Example:
I have developed a django Application which contains four apps inside called app_1, app_2, app_3 and app_4.
Now I want to deploy app_1 on server_1, app_2 on sever_2, app_3 on server_3 and app_4 on server_4.
Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

No, i don't think deploying each apps to different server is possible if all the apps are entitled same project.